# Highlighting não funciona nas views Razor MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, visual-studio-2012

Estou com um projeto Razor ASP.NET MVC 5 que foi criado no VS2013 em outro computador. Ao carregar ele no meu computador com o VS2012 o highlighting e o IntelliSense das Views (cshtml) não funcionam.

Percebi que meu VS2012 não tinha o MVC 5, se eu criasse um novo projeto não aparecia a opção para criar usando MVC 5. Então instalei o AspNet WebTools 2013_1, agora posso criar projetos MVC 5, mas ainda assim não funciona o highlighting.

Antes de fazer essa instalação fiz várias outras [tentativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542813/intellisense-in-mvc4-project-not-working-in-vs-2012-professional) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense) além de outras que já não tenho mais os links. Também refiz algumas dessas tentativas após a instalação do AspNet WebTools 2013_1.

Para os projetos onde uso o MVC 4 tudo funciona normalmente.

Baixei em outras duas máquinas que também possuem o VS2012 com configurações parecidas com a minha e acontece o mesmo problema. Em máquinas com VS2013 o problema não ocorre.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e tem alguma dica para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Nem se você criar um projeto novo do zero do MVC 5 funciona?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Mesmo criando do zero não funciona.

Comment: OMG! Duvido que trocar o Visual Studio seja uma opção né!?

Comment: É a máquina da empresa @MiguelAngelo, essa não é uma opção :(
O VS2013 onde ele foi criado é de uma terceira que foi contratada pra atuar no desenvolvimento também.

Comment: Acabei de testar em mais uma máquina que aparentemente o VS2012 está exatamente igual ao meu e está funcionando.
Importei as configurações para o meu VS mas problema continua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unica forma que consegui resolver o problema foi fazendo a instalação do VS2013.
Talvez a reinstalação do 2012 funcionasse pois em uma máquina que possuía essa versão com update 5 funcionava todos os recursos do MVC5, mas como consegui a atualização optei por já instalar a versão 2013 e evitar problemas com outros projetos.