# Views não reconhecem @model, @ViewBag, @ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, visual-studio, razor

Estou utilizando Mono 5.10.1 e Visual Studio Professional for Mac (Version 7.5.4 build 3)

As Views não reconhecem tags como @model, @ViewBag e @ViewData, tanto em projetos antigos que originalmente foram criados no Visual Studio 2017 Windows, como em um simples new project utilizando .Net Framework 4.6.1

Coloquei no GIT um projeto padrão criado, mesmo nele as Views não reconhecem as tags, porem baixando o projeto em um Visual Studio 2017 Windows as tags são reconhecidas normalmente.
GIT: https://github.com/DanielGregatto/TesteRazor

Alguém já passou por isso? Já estou pesquisando a alguns dias.

Comment: Ele não reconhece no editor ou também apresenta erro na execução?

Comment: Apenas no editor, o build funciona normalmente.

Comment: Não sei se você chegou a ver isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense  É o mesmo problema?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade Sim, já tentei esta solução. Apaguei todas as preferências e cache do VS.

Comment: @DanielGregatto Mas é o mesmo problema, digo, a descrição do problema é o mesma que você está experimentando neste momento?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade Sim

Comment: Já tive problema parecido e vou apenas relacionar aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141896/highlighting-n%C3%A3o-funciona-nas-views-razor-mvc-5

Comment: Isso acontece porque o seu projeto não está reconhecendo a biblioteca Razor. Via NuGet, confira qual a versão do Razor que está instalado no seu projeto. Em seguida, acesse os arquivos **packages.config** e **Web.config** e revise as versões dessa biblioteca. Podem haver mais de uma referência e não deixe de verificar o arquivo **Web.config** presente **também na pasta Views**. Vale lembrar que o arquivo **packages.config** cita a versão bruta do pacote, que pode ser diferente da versão citada no **Web.config**.